# How to identify guest user using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, cookies, encryption

My website is an e-commerce where users can add items to their carts. Each user has a cart even if he/she doesn't login (i.e. a guest user). I would like to identify the guest users by put some kind of `key` to their cookies.

**I wonder if Spring Framework can handle this already?**

**If that is not the case**, I have to implement it myself but I am not sure about the `key` to put in the cookies. I know about `HMAC` but the key need to be unique, right? **What is the algorithm should I use to generate the `key` in this case?**

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use the default anonymous user for that?

Comment: @M.Deinum, sorry for late response. It because I would like to persist his cart in the database, so that when he revisit the website later, the cart will still be there. Thus I need something to identify him. By the way, I am not sure what is the "default anonymous user" to Spring Framework. Does Spring already keep track of the anonymous users? thanks.

Comment: spring-security does not write any session indicator for the AnonymousAuthenticationToken, see the org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain).

Comment: in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045564/how-to-manage-guest-sessions-in-spring-boot said you can force spring to add JSESSIONID and you can get JSESSIONID  after this.

Answer (score 1):

As I have the same requirement, I wrote [spring-security-guest](https://github.com/sutra/spring-security-guest), it uses a X-Client-Token HTTP header generated by client side to start a new session.